# Safari 100vw Layout issue when zoomed - Help me understand

Tags: css, safari, viewport-units

Has anyone seen an issue where Safari and zooming out? I have a div that has a width of `100vw`, and when I zoom out, the 100vw does not re-calculate.

I know that there are some quirks to viewport units, and documented on the [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) page, however none of them seem to be what I am seeing. Am I missing a corresponding property somewhere?

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vax8Lga/) that demonstrates the issue. Load it up in Safari and zoom out: https://jsfiddle.net/4vax8Lga/

```html
<body>
<div style="background: red; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; color: white">
  100%width
  <p>Zoom out to see if I fill the entire screen<p>
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: Checked your jsFiddle just change the width from width:100vw; to width:100%; and it works as expected. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that 100% works here, however there are cases where vw solves other issues. This example doesn't demonstrate the uses of vw over percentage, however it is meant to show that Safari and zooming have issues with vw. 

I am hoping that that someone has seen this issue and has some feedback on it, while still using vw.

Answer (score 0):

caniuse is actually missing the information on this bug. I reported it elsewhere, but same answer:

This was a bug in Safari, which was reportedly closed in November 2017. It's unclear if it will land in Safari 12 or not.

Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145614

Changeset: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/225277/webkit